# Receiving a callback from the EndCall event

Tags: android, button, keyevent

The app I am developing needs to know when someone presses the End Call button. It doesn't need to alter the button's function at all. It merely needs to know when it is pressed. I would just like to know if this is possible and how to do this?

I have been looking at the KeyEvent class, but I am unable to implement it. I don't even know if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I highly [doubt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998278/android-capture-suppress-home-and-endcall-buttons-events) you can do this ... trapping key events that are not in your application is just [malicious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777596/how-to-block-the-dial-home-back-and-end-call-button-on-android) code.

---

Maybe you are interested in knowing if a call has been terminated?

If so: use the [`PhoneStateListener`](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130519/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html) to [detect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872214/how-do-i-get-state-of-a-outgoing-call-in-android-phone) state transitions from `CALL_STATE_RINGING/CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` to `CALL_STATE_IDLE`

Comment: Thank you for your response. :-) but unfortunately just checking the state change isn't sufficient for the app. There are certain functions that would make life easier if i could get the event but alas, i shall make a work around